# Optional elements in a collection depending on condition with no additional filtering in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find the best way to only conditionally add an element to a collection. Let me try to explain.

Let:

```
val a="1234"
val b="1arst"
val c=""
```

(you can see i'm using a colemak layout I bet)

I want to make a map but only include an element only if its length is greater than one.

I can go:

```
Map("a" -> a, "b" ->b, "c"->c).filter(_._2.length>0)
```

which gives me the desired map:

```
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = 
Map(a -> 1234, b -> 1arst)
```

I can also do things like:

```
Map(
if(a.length>0) "a"->a else "" -> "" ,
if(b.length>0) "b"->b else "" -> "" , 
if(c.length>0) "c"->c else "" -> "" )
```

But this gives me an undesired empty string value in the map which I still need to filter:

```
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(a -> 1234, b -> 1arst, "" -> "")
```

So I was thinking of using right associative operators against a Nil but that also doesn't work as you end up with an empty list item in the list.

> scala> "test" -> "test" :: Nil :: "test"->"test" :: Nil res1:
>   List[Product with Serializable] = List((test,test), List(),
>   (test,test))

Is there a more efficient way to get this done without filtering over all the elements a second time to remove any 0 length items?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568634/scala-conditional-list-construction/15575066#15575066 for a similar question and a few answers to that.

Comment: Why you unhappy with filter? It is rather readable then tons of conditions inside Map.

Comment: @Impredicative thanks. I like the some/none solution with flatten too.

Comment: Still these solutions require two trips through the map which seems sub-optimal. Alas "premature optimization is the mother of all evil"